# Mathematicians who died extraordinary deaths

Tags: soft-question

Évariste Galois, the pioneer of Galois theory, died at the age of twenty from wounds sustained in a duel; the duel was apparently over a woman Galois was interested in.

Oswald Teichmüller, a brilliant mathematician who made contributions to complex analysis and invented the theory of Teichmuller spaces, was in fact a fanatical Nazi who died fighting for Hitler on the Eastern Front in $1943$.

What are some other examples of mathematicians whose lives ended in bizarre ways?

Comment: Hypatia was a mathematician  from the Alexandrian school and she was slain by Christians in 415.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Gödel "Later in his life, Gödel suffered periods of mental instability and illness. He had an obsessive fear of being poisoned; he would eat only food that his wife, Adele, prepared for him. Late in 1977, she was hospitalized for six months and could no longer prepare her husband's food. In her absence, he refused to eat, eventually starving to death. He weighed 65 pounds (approximately 30 kg) when he died. His death certificate reported that he died of "malnutrition and inanition caused by personality disturbance" in Princeton Hospital on January 14, 1978."

Comment: Evariste Galois pioneered group theory, actually (which is much broader than Galois theory). I wonder what more cool stuff he could have done. Really sad they didn't develop better methods to try and tame him.

Comment: Witold Hurewicz. Quote from [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witold_Hurewicz): He died after participating in the International Symposium on Algebraic Topology at the National Autonomous University of Mexico in Mexico City. He tripped and fell off the top of a Mayan step pyramid during an outing in Uxmal, Mexico. In the Dictionary of Scientific Biography it is suggested that he was "...a paragon of absentmindedness, a failing that probably led to his death."

Answer (score 3):

> Noli turbare circulos meos*

... said Archimedes before he was killed by a roman soldier with his sword, back in  212 BC during the capture of the city of Syracuse.

*) *"Don't disturb my circles"* (Latin)

Comment: "Don't disturb my circles" ?

Comment: Yes. He obviously did not say that in English.

Comment: Obviously most users here only understand English

Comment: Obviously it's one of the most known Latin quotes. Not as popular as *veni vidi vici* though.

Comment: Actually that line is taken from a text written in latin that talks about Archimedes, he most certainly said it in ancient Greek

Comment: @Peterix To a Roman soldier?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN I would bet that a large majority of users here understand at least one language besides English.  However, English is likely the only language spoken by a large majority of users here.

Comment: @Peterix - μὴ μου τοὺς κύκλους τάραττε unless you want to tell me he spoke in capital letters

Comment: Wow @Henry do you know Greek or just googled it?

Comment: @EricWong of course! I meant to say most users won't understand Latin

Comment: @Peterix I did (just) pass an exam in Ancient Greek over 35 years ago but, as you guessed, I Googled it.  Learning Greek did me no good in Mathematics as I wrote *gamma* as $\gamma$ and was then told to write it with a loop